# Word count in PIG

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Assume I have a text file name count.txt which contains below mentioned paragraph

```
    I am working  in hadoop along with  various courses like Hadoop, Hana, Java etc
    I love working with hadoop
    This is hadoop project
```

Now I need to get How many times the word hadoop occured in the above file

The following code is what I have tried

```
    c1= load '/...../count.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (Name:chararray);
    c2 = foreach c1  generate FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(LOWER(Name)))as (Name1:chararray);
    dump c2;
    c3 = filter c2 by Name1=='hadoop';
    dump c3;
```

here output I am getting as

```
(hadoop)
(hadoop)
(hadoop)
(hadoop)
```

What I need is the numeral 4,not the word hadoop repeated 4 times. hence i tried to execute

```
`c4 = foreach c3 generate COUNT($0);`
```

and getting error..Kindly do help me,may be a simple thing which I am unable to find.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Just do a group of c2:

```
c3 = filter c2 by Name1=='hadoop'
grouped = GROUP c3 BY Name1;
wordcount = FOREACH grouped GENERATE $0, COUNT($1);
DUMP wordcount
```

Let me know if it helps.